# ScrollBar on a readonly TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, css

The TextArea is in readonly mode using "ng-readonly" hence the scrollbar-thumb is not appearing. I am not using webkit. My html code is as below:

```
<textarea dataitemfqn="ClientBulletin.Handling.WCUniqueInstructions.ReturnToWork.SpecialHandlingInstructions3" 
          id="SpecialHandlingInstructions3"                                      
          ng-model="ClientBulletin.HandlingData.Handling.SpecialHandlingInstructions3" 
          ng-readonly="BulletinEditMode == false" 
          class="textarea-scrollbar" 
          onkeyup="resizeTextarea('SpecialHandlingInstructions3')">
</textarea>
```

---

The css is as follows:

```
.textarea-scrollbar {
    /*overflow:scroll !important;*/    
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    resize: both !important;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    min-height:50px;
    max-height:200px;    
}

.textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

.textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

--
The JavaScript is as follows:

```
function resizeTextarea(id) {
    var a = document.getElementById(id);
    a.style.height = '50px';
    a.style.height = a.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

function init() {
    var a = document.getElementById('SpecialHandlingInstructions3');
    for (var i = 0, inb = a.length; i < inb; i++) {
        if (a[i].getAttribute('data-resizable') == 'true')
            resizeTextarea(a[i].id);
    }
}
```

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
//

```
$(function () {
    $('#SpecialHandlingInstructions3').each(function () {
        $(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));        
    });
});
```

The ScrollBar-Thumb is not comming up. My client is strictle looking for the ScrollBar-Thumb and not TextArea resizing.
I even tried embedding the TextArea within a Div but still i am not getting the expected result. Kindly help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added the css you suggested but still it is not working as expected (scrollbar thumb not appearing).

    .textarea-scrollbar {
        /*overflow:scroll !important;*/    
        overflow-y: scroll !important;
        height: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 120px;
        resize: both !important;
        -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
        min-height:50px;
        max-height:200px;    
    }

    .textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to at least customize the scrollbar in order for the "child elements" to have effect. For example, try adding the following CSS:

```
.textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
```

Then `.textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` will work as well.

```css
.textarea-scrollbar {
    /*overflow:scroll !important;*/    
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    resize: both !important;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    min-height:50px;
    max-height:200px;    
}

.textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

.textarea-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea-scrollbar" placeholder="Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum Lorum Ipsum">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added the code snipet but it is not working as expected

Comment: It is a webkit only function, so it works only in Chrome, and would not in Firefox or Internet Explorer. What browser are you testing in?

Comment: I am using IE11

Comment: Then I suggest looking into a plugin to style scrollbars, as not all browsers support this natively. https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar for example should solve this problem for you.

Comment: My TextArea is readonly using ng-readonly hence the scrollbar-thumb is not showing. Can you please suggest of any trick to overcome this issue

Comment: Scopestyle will it be possible to take any other option other than using a plugin as i am not sure if my client will be ok with it.

Comment: I'm affraid not. As Firefox and Internet Explorer simply do not support any CSS styling of the scrollbar. Using a plugin really is your only option. If you have doubts I suggest checking with your client and explain the situation. If it's no problem moving forward with Javascript simply use the plugin. If not, abandon the styling of the scrollbar alltogether.

Comment: Ok Thanks Scopestyle for your suggestion. I will discuss this with the client. Keeping this question open for further suggestions. THANKS